# compare td value and set rank dynamically

Tags: jquery

Values in `td` are generated from PHP, now requirement is to compare these values and set rank such as ('1,2,3...') based on value, dynamically using jquery. For example I have set static rank `1` for highest values in following snippet. But I can't figure it out - how to loop dynamically and set rank through jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var high = Math.max.apply(Math, $('.rank').map(function(){
    return $(this).text()
  }))
  $('.rank').each(function(){
    var mark = $(this).text();
    if(mark == high){ 
      $(this).find('span#rank').text(' (1)');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td class='rank'>20<span id='rank'></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jack</td>
        <td class='rank'>40<span id='rank'></span></td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Multiple Tr are here, generated from php -->
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `id` needs to be unique in the document. To get the rank:

1. Get all the ranks and store them in an array
2. Sort this array in ascending order
3. Re-iterate on `.rank` and get the index of the current rank in the previous array
4. This will be your absolute rank.

```js
let allRanks = [];
$('.rank').each(function(){
    allRanks.push( +$(this).text() );
})
allRanks.sort();

$(".rank").each(function(){
  let rankVal = +$(this).text();
  let rank = allRanks.indexOf(rankVal)+1;
  $(this).find(".innerrank").html(" ("+rank+")")
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td class='rank'>20<span class='innerrank'></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jack</td>
        <td class='rank'>40<span class='innerrank'></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jack</td>
        <td class='rank'>30<span class='innerrank'></span></td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Multiple Tr are here, generated from php -->
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

PS: You might need to handle the case when multiple rank values are same.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array with numbers in rank divs, then sort it and iterate. while iterating, find rank divs containing number and put rank as index + 1.

See below code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arr = new Array();
  $('.rank').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).text());
  });
  arr.sort();
  $.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
    $('.rank:contains(' + value + ')').find('span.rankNumber').html(index+1);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td class='rank'>20<span class='rankNumber'></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jack</td>
        <td class='rank'>40<span class='rankNumber'></span></td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Multiple Tr are here, generated from php -->
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: clean solution and well described description, Thanks